# Pass multiple arguments to a custom filter Django

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2, django-template-filters

I have a custom filter that looks like this

```html
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def makebreadcrumbs(value, arg):
    pass
```

How can I pass multiple arguments to the filter?

```html
  {% with request.resolver_match.namespace as name_space %}
    {{ request.path|makebreadcrumbs:name_space|safe }}
  {% endwith %}
```

In the code above `makebreadcrumbs` is my custom filter, `request.path` is a variable (value), and `name_space` is an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is a [Django simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) which can accept multiple arguments:

```py
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def breadcrumbs(path, name_space):
   # your code
   return ...
```

```html
{% breadcrumbs request.path request.resolver_match.namespace %}
```

Comment: by using ```{% ``` django template throw error ```django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag```
i guess we need to use {{ instead?

Comment: The documentation says to use `{% %}` - you might have a block error elsewhere?

Comment: Yes actually it was having issue elsewhere, i got it running by using `{%`